# Zero incorrectly assigned in Hungarian algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.4, hungarian-algorithm

I am writing a hungarian algorithm from scratch in Python 3.4, and have run in to a problem regarding optimal lines to cover zeros.

I took the definition of the algorithm from its Wikipedia page, and this is the code for finding the minimum lines to cover all of the zeros:

```
def minZeroLines(matrix):

    markMatrix = [] #first for marked rows, second for marked columns

    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        markMatrix.append([])
        for col in range(len(matrix)):
            markMatrix[row].append("")

    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for col in range(len(matrix)):
            if matrix[row][col] == 0 and ("*" not in [i[col] for i in markMatrix] and "*" not in markMatrix[row]):
                markMatrix[row][col] = "*"

    print(markMatrix)

    rowColMark = [[],[]] #1st rows, 2nd cols

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        rowColMark[0].append("")
        rowColMark[1].append("")

    for row in range(len(markMatrix)):
        if "*" not in markMatrix[row]:
            rowColMark[0][row] = "x"

    print(rowColMark)

    for row in range(len(markMatrix)):
        if rowColMark[0][row] == "x":
            for col in range(len(matrix)):
                if matrix[row][col] == 0:
                    rowColMark[1][col] = "x"
                    for row2 in range(len(markMatrix)):
                        if matrix[row2][col] == 0 and markMatrix[row2][col] == "*":
                            rowColMark[0][row2] = "x"

    print(rowColMark)

    lineList = []

    for col in range(len(rowColMark[1])):
        if rowColMark[1][col] == "x":
            lineList.append("c"+str(col))

    for row in range(len(rowColMark[0])):
        if rowColMark[0][row] != "x":
            lineList.append("r"+str(row))

    print(rowColMark)
    print(lineList)
    return lineList
```

The problem is that when I run the matrix below through it, during the initial assignment of zeros as a first step in finding the least lines to cover them, the zero at matrix[1][1] is chosen. This causes the function to later on mark all of the rows, meaning they will not be lined, even though clearly the row matrix[1] should be.

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
      [0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
      [0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
      [0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
      [0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]]
```

This is the part that seems to be causing problems:

```
for row in range(len(matrix)):
    for col in range(len(matrix)):
        if matrix[row][col] == 0 and ("*" not in [i[col] for i in markMatrix] and "*" not in markMatrix[row]):
            markMatrix[row][col] = "*"
```

I'm thinking that there must be some condition I am missing that will stop that zero being assigned, but this is not detailed in the description I looked at, and in other places. Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: http://csclab.murraystate.edu/~bob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html has an algorithm description and c# code.  It was clear enough that I was able translate it to Python (with numpy) in half a day.